# Getting the Global Variable to change based on increment defined within an onclick function?

Tags: javascript, function, this, return-value, counter

Just want to say what a great forum this is for developers and IT professionals.

I have this code below. I am trying to get the count value outside of the function that the count is being processed in. But its not working, even with a global variable to that function. 
Is there anyway this can be done?

Thanks for your help guys, much appreciated.

```
var getcountglobal =0;
var that =this.buttonforitem; //this refers to button created by javascript

that.onclick = function()
{

   getcountglobal++;
   console.log(getcountglobal);// in console when clicking the button it gives 1,2,3,etc

} 
console.log(getcountglobal); // here it gives 0 and not the click number. Why doesn't or cant the variable be changed?
```

Comment: Why do you expect the variable to change before the function ever runs?

Comment: sorry for the typo in the last line, it should be : console.log(getcountglobal); Thanks

Comment: Hi SLaks, I thought the variable is being changed when I click the button? How would this work in terms of the code? Thanks

Comment: The last console only writes once: when it is running the first time and initializing the global variable and the click event.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone. With the console.log instead the function clicks are being registered. But I don't see a way of getting that value outside of the function?

Comment: @JesalMavadiya You are over-thinking this. You read the global value when you want it! Click the button a few times. In the console type `console.log(getcountglobal);` TADA, you got the updated value.

Comment: @epascarello I understand your point of reading the variable getcountglobal within the function, but what i want to do with that value is, multiply it by the price of an item. The clicks are counting adding quantities of items to a basket. So my question is can that variable be used outside of that.onclick function, to be used somewhere else? Sorry if I am confusing you.

Comment: The variable can be used anywhere. Problem is the fact you are expecting that console.log outside of the function call to magically update after the inside does. It does not. It is a "snapshot" of that moment in time. You read the value as zero and you write that out. If you want to get the new value, you need to read it again. So if you want to update the total, you would need to call a function after the update to recalculate it.

Comment: @epascarello ahh I understand that at the point I called it, the value was 0. so to get the new value, how would I go about creating a function to get that, would I have to use the current function that I have been looking at? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that, console.log(getcountergloba); gets executed irrespective of click because it is outside the event handler (onclick). Once somebody clicks, that variable is incremented and prints the correct number. But, when you print it outside the eventhandler, it executes before any event occurs and at that time it's value is 0

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that the console.log that is printing out 0 is being called before you ever click the button. It is printing out zero immediately after assigning a click handler to your button.

Answer (score 0):

```
that.onclick = function()
{

   getcountglobal++;
   console.log(getcountglobal);// in console when clicking the button it gives 1,2,3,etc

   console.log(getcounterglobal);//move this in your click

}
```

The variable is being changed every click.  The problem is your only printing it on page load when global is 0.

Move console.log in your click otherwise it will only be ran the first time page is loaded when global = 0.